# How to add the multiple integers

Tags: javascript

I have the following values. How to add them using JavaScript?

```
var test = '' + 2 + 3 + '' + 6;
```

It gives the following output:

```
236
```

Comment: what is the expected output? 11?

Comment: are you trying to sum them up or you are trying to get the number 236?

Comment: Yes i want the output 11

Comment: `number + string = string`. Remove the string and you will get the result you want.

Comment: don't put string in there

Comment: Remove `''` from statement. It will add the numbers.

Comment: `var test = 2 + 3 + 6;` or just `var test = 11;`.

Comment: this isn't a `jquery` thing, it's just how **javascript** works (jquery has no effect on basic operations like this)

Answer (score 4):

You should parse the "string numbers".

```
Number('') + 2 + 3 + Number('') + 6
```